# WP8 Photo Viewer similar to the one used by the Photos App

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am working on an app which has an album of photos. I want the user to be able to click one of them to bring up a page to watch/zoom/etc them seperately, exactly like it works in the Photo App and in the Store app.

I have been experimenting with a scrollviewer and a vertical stackpanel but I can't figure out how to make it work as intended. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you describe the specific issue? In what way is your solution not working as intended.

Comment: If you open an album in the Photo App and tap one of the photos a new view will be brought up. From there you can zoom the picture, or swipe to the next one. If you zoom out you can see the pictures lining up next to each other. Tapping a photo will zoom in the tapped photo. I haven't found any way to implement such behaviour. The best I have so far is a View showing one photo, which i can zoom and move around. Swiping will simply reopen the same view with a new photo. I haven't found much information on the Internet, which makes me believe I'm missing something obvious here...

Answer (score 0):

Well I would think it should be possible to use a pivot control, because this comes with the swiping feature for free!
Only thing to do is loading the images in a dynamic way, because preloading them all will eat up to much memory.

For the zooming, there are several solutions to be found on the internet ( like [this one...](http://codecopy.wordpress.com/2011/12/15/wp7-pinch-and-pan-zoom-an-image/) ) but the trick is to keep track of the initial zoom loading state of the image. Because as long as you are in that state, the user must be able to use the swipe of the pivot.
If you are not in the initial zoom loading state, you must lock the current pivot! ( wp8 pivot has this build in with the property isLocked for wp7 you can use [this...](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/windows-phone-toolkit-lockablepivot-in-depth) )

The get a headerless pivot, just put an empty datatemplate in the headertemplate:

> ```
>             <controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
>                 <DataTemplate />
>             </controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [Basic Lens sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Basic-Lens-sample-359fda1b). You don't need the camera functionality, but it's being hosted in a control very similar to the photos app from the MediaViewer library project. The only thing it's missing is the most zoomed out view, which you should be able to add yourself as a StackPanel in a ScrollViewer.